# Using NIC Teaming on Windows Server 2012 with 2 separate Networks

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-teaming

I am trying to set up **NIC Teaming** on my Windows Server 2012 which has **two incoming connections** from different ISPs (**ISP A** and **ISP B**) on **2 NICs** on the server. Internally I have configured the **1st NIC with ISP A** on `.100.x` and **2nd NIC with ISP B** on `.200.x`.

My query is, how do I smartly configure the NIC Teaming such that when the connection from `ISP A` fails, the other **2nd NIC** takes takes over and still do the work of both networks?

Comment: Do it's only to support user, or you have too internet traffic coming in for your servers ? (like email, hosted webserver, etc..) As if you have traffic coming in, you need adjust the domain host record to redirect to the good place.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this.  It is absolutely the wrong technology to use to connect to different networks.  NIC teaming is for resilience and aggregation to a single network.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of teaming the NICs, you need a load balancer or a wan failover device. You can do that on Windows Server by following this Technet Guide http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh831698.aspx .